# How to print 5 values per line in C++ using only loop statement and no if-statements?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I want to write a program that prints numbers from 1 to 50 with 6 values per line and have a blank space between the values. I need to use only a for loop statement without using an if statement.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int e;

    for(int a = 1, int b = 2, int c = 3, int d = 4, int e = 5; a <= 50, b <= 50, c <= 50, d <= 50, e <= 50; a++, b++, c++, d++, e++) {
        cout << a << "  "<< b<< "  "<< c << "  "<< d<< "  "<< e <<"  " << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the program if I used an if-statement, but I am unsure how to compile this without using the if-statement:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
    cout << i << "  ";
        if(i % 5 == 0)
            cout << endl;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @user3271156 Edit your post, don't post the code as a comment.

Comment: @user3271156, embed that, nicely formatted, in your original question please

Comment: @user3271156, better! Could you explain to us the use of the ints `a, b, c, d, e`? Put another way, is it absolutely necessary to do it like that?

Comment: @user3271156 Does the code compile?

Comment: @pauluss86 I thought it is necessary because I want to put 5 values on one line. if I wanted to use an if statement, I wouldn't need those values, all I would need is a line: "if(i % 5 ==0)"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ; I'd suspect not due to the redeclaration of the integers.

Comment: @user3271156 Think about a solution with two nested `for` loops ...

Comment: One more question: is the ternary operator `foo ? x : y;` considered an if-statement here?

Comment: I included the if statement in my original post, this compiled correctly, but I am unsure how to get rid of the if statement and only use for loops?

Comment: @user3271156 the hint given by πάντα ῥεῖ is basically your solution.

Comment: I'm baffled by the judicious downvoting. Surely a downvote is not meant for 'grading' the code given in a question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing what you're looking for is something similar to this?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
   for(int i = 0; i <= 50; ++i)
   { 
      ((i % 6) == 5) ? cout << i << '\n' : cout << i << ' ';
   }
   return 0;
}
```

nested for loop example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
    { 
        for( int j = 0; j <= 5; ++j)
        {
            cout << (i) << ' ';
            ++i;
        }
        cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but some (mostly style-related) comments: `endl` flushes the output stream, which is not necessary as this is done when `main()` returns anyway. Use pre-increment in the inner loop (`i++` ). There's no need to stream a string literal containing a single character (`cout << " "`), instead just do `cout << ' '`. Matter of taste: the `return 0;` is obviously correct, but a `return 0;` is implicitly added if not done so explicitly. Lastly, the parenthesis can be safely removed: `cout << i << ' ';` instead of `cout << (i) << " "`.

Comment: Oh and for your first solution, I was taught that the ternary operator should 'return something useful', the compiler didn't complain so I'm not quite sure. In any case, the `cout << i` part can be factored out as it is common to both 'branches'.

Comment: yeah it was more just a quick example i rushed (at work lol), have to agree with your comments.

Comment: Don't let your boss see that code ;-) Anyway, the reason I made the comments is because the person asking the question is clearly learning C++ so it can't hurt to give more information than the bare minimum to solve his current problem.

Comment: haha cheeky! yeah no it was a nice follow up and have to agree, to be fair my answer was a "you can do this sort of thing" although the whole not being able to use if-statements sounds a little bit like cw to me. Obviously best not to rush code when typing on here, hard to proof read.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   for(size_t i = 1; i <= 50; ++i)
       cout << i << (i % 6 ? ' ' : '\n');
}
```

Comment: when you use    (i % 6 ? ' ' : '\n');    ,is there another way of not using the question mark and the colon?

Comment: Yes, but in that case the only solution that immediately enters my mind is the nested for-loop as given in Mike's answer.

Comment: Note that an 'if-statement' is strictly speaking about flow-control. 'Conditional assignment' (the `x ? y : z;`) is, as far as I know, not regarded as simply a shorthand notation of an if-statement. What I'm trying to say is, if your assignment only forbids if-statements then I would regard the conditional assignment in my answer as allowed.